# Is there a more efficient way to assess containment of strings?

Tags: java, performance, math

I have to execute this line of cose several million times, I wonder if there is a way to optimize it (maybe precomputing something?).

`a.contains(b) || b.contains(a)`

Thank you

edit: the code executed by the contains method already checks for a.length < b.length.

```
public static int indexOf(byte[] value, int valueCount, byte[] str, int strCount, int fromIndex) {
    byte first = str[0];
    int max = (valueCount - strCount);
    for (int i = fromIndex; i <= max; i++) {
        [...]
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Is `a` or `b` constant?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If we could see more code, we may be able to optimize it better.

Comment: Unfortunately ```a``` and ```b``` are not constant.

I want to know if a word is a substring of another word, given a dictionary of nearly 35 M words.

Comment: Do you want to check whether two words contain each other for each pair of two words from those 35 million, or for one _other_ word and each of those 35 million?

Comment: The first one you said, for each pair of words contained into the dictionary.

Comment: Maybe you could narrow the search down with n-grams, let's say trigrams. If `a` contains some trigram, then `b` has to contain the same trigram. You could precompute all the trigrams that each word in the list contains, and at the same time all the words that contain a given trigram, then you can just look up the words in those dictionaries and with some set operations. (If there are words shorter than 3 letters you might do the same with bigrams and/or single letters)

Comment: In fact my task can be restated as ```lcs(a, b).equals(a) || lcs(a, b).equals(a)```, with lcs the longest-common-substring

Comment: tobias, you just give me a useful hint! thank you, I'll think about your solution and I'll make some tests

Comment: You need to look up the Boyer-Moore search algorithm, and, for completeness, the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm, which isn't quite as fast (I tested them).

Comment: @user207421 But even then, won't OP still have to check each of the 35M² combinations of words? Maybe if you (virtually?) concatenate all the words to a single text and then search in that text you could skip ahead quite fast, but this will not really reduce the complexity, right? For finding a single word in those 35M, this might work well, tough.

Comment: @tobias_k Certainly, but the actual search is the inner loop, which merits the most attention, and can be radically improved from what was posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the task, you have to check whether `a` contains `b` or vice versa for each pair of `a` and `b` from a set of about 35 million words. That's a lot of pairs to check.

You should be able to narrow the search down considerable by precomputing which n-grams a word contains: If `a` contains some n-gram, then `b` has to contain the same n-gram if `b` contains `a`. You could e.g. precompute all the trigrams that each word in the list contains, and at the same time all the words that contain a given trigram, then you can just look up the words in those dictionaries and with some set operations get a small set of candidates to check properly.

In pseudo-code:

- select a size for the n-grams (see below)
- initialize a `Map<String, Set<String>> ngram_to_word`
- first iteration: for each word `a` in your data set

  - iterate all the n-grams (e.g. using some sort of sliding window) of `a`
  - for each, add `a` to the sets of words containing those n-grams in `ngrams_to_words`
- second iteration: for each word `a` in your data set

  - again get all the n-grams `a` contains
  - for each of those, get the set of words that contain that n-gram from `ngrams_to_words`
  - get the intersection of those sets of words
  - for each word `b` in that intersection that contains all the n-grams that `a` contains (but maybe in a different order or quantity), properly check whether `b` contains `a`

Depending on the number of letters in those n-grams (e.g. bigrams, trigrams, ...), they will be more expensive to pre-compute, in both time and space, but the effect will also be greater. In the simplest case, you could even just precompute which words contain a given letter (i.e. "1-grams"); that should be fast and already considerable narrow down the words to check. Of course, the n-grams should not be shorter than the shortest of the words in the data set, but you could even use two length of n-grams, e.g. use two maps `letter_to_words` and `trigrams_to_words`.

Comment: thank you tobias, I'll try your solution and I'll post my results here